# Is it possible to connect to the Lichess database remotely from ChessBase?

Tags: database, chessbase, lichess

Lichess has a database of over 200 million blitz, rapid and classical games played on the website, that can be accessed via the [opening explorer](https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer). That is extremely useful for those interested in preparing openings for online games, which often deviate from the main lines.

I'd like to shift to ChessBase for opening preparation, however, and the only way that I know of to access the aforementioned database is to [download it](https://database.lichess.org/#standard_games). I don't have enough space to store that many games so my sample size would be many orders of magnitude smaller. Is it possible to connect to the Lichess database remotely from ChessBase?

Comment: Just want to point out that even if you downloaded the games, at least my older version of chessbase couldn't handle more than some 10 million games.

Comment: As for a way to use Chessbase, I would recommend simply using both, check the opening explorer on lichess and copy the moves into your Chessbase window. I've certainly done similar things before.

Comment: lichess has an API, so it is theoretically possible for third-party applications to access the opening explorer. However, I'm not aware that ChessBase supports lichess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the online Chess base database. When you have some position open in the Chess base program and you are connected to wifi, you can click “enter” on your board or press this button, and the newest version of the database will appear, which includes blitz, rapid, and classic tournaments in real life and titled tournaments of chess.com
[image: click this button image]